# Problem looping through files (using Powershell) and moving them one at a time, based on error result

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I am using Powershell to validate multiple XML files against multiple XSDs; this portion of the code is working as expected, however I also need to move any XML which fails to validate to an "Invalid" folder. I am attempting to loop through these files using ForEach, and then - using an If statement - to move any file which errored. My problem is that all files are being moved, whether or not they errored.

I've written this loop in as many different ways as I could conceive, but I'm not getting the result I expect. (I have also scoured the web for days to find the answer.) I need ForEach to apply the code to each file, one at a time. Is this a problem with my syntax? Perhaps I'm missing something very obvious, but I'm now at a loss.

I am using this function (found on Stack Overflow, and as shown here, slightly tweaked) to validate the XMLs.

```
function Test-XmlFile
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Validates an xml file against an xml schema file.
    .Example
        PS> dir *.xml | Test-XmlFile schema.xsd
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (     
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        $SchemaFile,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$true)]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [alias('Fullname')]
        $XmlFile,

        [scriptblock] $ValidationEventHandler = { Write-Error $args[1].Exception }
    )

    begin {
        $schemaReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader $SchemaFile
        $schema = [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema]::Read($schemaReader, $ValidationEventHandler)
    }

    process {
        $ret = $true
        try {
            $xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
            $xml.Schemas.Add($schema) | Out-Null
            $xml.Load($XmlFile)
            $xml.Validate({
                    throw ([PsCustomObject] @{
                        SchemaFile = $SchemaFile
                        XmlFile = $XmlFile
                        Exception = $args[1].Exception
                    })
                })
        } catch {
            Write-Error $_
            $ret = $false
        }
        $ret
    }

    end {
        $schemaReader.Close()
    }
}
```

And here is how I am selecting XMLs for validation against their given schemas.

```
$allfiles = "..\Schema Validation\XMLs\*.xml"

$xml1 = Get-ChildItem $allfiles -Recurse | Select-String "<UniqueElement>" -List | Resolve-Path
$xml2 = Get-ChildItem $allfiles -Recurse | Select-String "<UniqueElement>" -List | Resolve-Path

$xsd1 = "..\Schema Validation\Schemas\Schema1.xsd"
$xsd2 = "..\Schema Validation\Schemas\Schema2.xsd"
```

And here is the ForEach loop that's not working for me. (In its current configuration, though I've written it a dozen different ways.)

```
ForEach ($xml in $xml1) {
$xml | Test-XmlFile $xsd1
If ($Error) {
$Error[0].Exception, "`r" | Out-File "..\Schema Validation\Results\log.txt"
Move-Item $xml -Destination "..\Schema Validation\Invalid"
}}
```

The ForEach loop above is also repeated for the $xml2 and $xsd2 variables.
(And as you can see from the Out-File, I'm also capturing the exception message in a text file for a log of sorts.)

I expected only those XMLs which error and hit an exception to be moved, due to the "If ($Error)" statement and the fact that I'm attempting to loop through the files one at a time; however, what happens is that any XML which contains the unique string that identifies it as part of the $xml1 or $xml2 group is moved to the Invalid folder, error or no error. So what painfully obvious thing am I missing?? (Incidentally, the exception text populates the error log as expected, so at least that part is working as I hoped.)

EDIT: On second thought, I shouldn't say that the exception text populates the log "as expected". It does populate the log, but it writes the message to the log file once for each file included in the variable (each file in $xml1, for example), whether or not the file actually errored. So if there are two files in $xml1, but only one is invalid, the single exception message for that one invalid file will be written to the log twice. So it's writing something for every file that is looped, regardless of validity or errors. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Error` gives you a list of the *last* errors, it is not cleared if the previous operation succeeded - it will still contain the last encountered errors. So every file will be copied to the 'invalid' directory after the first error.

You already have error handling in your cmdlet, so you could modify that code to also handle moving the file to the other directory.

Comment: "_last_ errors" is a bit confusing; The automatic `$Error` variable is a collection of _all errors that have occurred in the current session_, in reverse chronological error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Test-XmlFile` function outputs a Boolean indicating the success status of the validation, so I suggest using that directly to determine validation success vs. failure; additionally, to capture the specifics of the validation failure use the `-ErrorVariable` common parameter:

```
ForEach ($xml in $xml1) {
  if (-not (Test-XmlFile -XmlFile $xml -SchemaFile $xsd1 -ErrorVariable err)) {
    $err.Exception, "`n" | Out-File -Append "..\Schema Validation\Results\log.txt"
    Move-Item $xml -Destination "..\Schema Validation\Invalid"
  }
}
```

Note that I've added `-Append` to your `Out-File` call to ensure that multiple failures don't overwrite each other in the log file. Also, it's better to use `` "`n" `` or `` "`r`n" `` or, platform-appropriately, `[Environment]::NewLine]` to create a newline (line break).

---

As for **what you tried**:

The automatic `$Error` variable is a collection (of type `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`) of *all* errors that have occurred in the *current session*, in reverse chronological error.

Thus, if you use `if ($Error)`, you're effectively asking if at least one error has occurred *in the session* so far, not whether the most recently executed command reported errors (the last of which would be reflected in `$Error[0]`), because `$Error` in a Boolean context evaluates to `$true` once the collection has at least one entry.

There is also the automatic `$?` variable, which is a Boolean that indicates whether the most recently executed command reported an error (at least one error) - unfortunately, however, this behavior is plagued with inconsistencies (any *expression* resets `$?` to `$true`, and `Write-Error` does *not* set `$?` to `$false`, unlike *compiled cmdlets* reporting errors), so it's better to rely on the explicit Boolean return value from `Test-XmlFile` in your case.